# Album art doesn't change

Tags: music, art

So I've been successfully using programs to change album arts for my cellphone for the past 3 years and something bothers me about the way that the actual app on the Samsung reverts this changes under the following circumstances:

If I've put a music from a specific album, for example, *Abbey Road*, with a specific album art, onto the memory card of my cell phone, and then I decide that I want to change the art, and so I delete this album from the memory card and just put the same one or a different one, it doesn't matter with a different art but with the same album name, *Abbey Road*, the app will automatically show the album art that was the first time *Abbey Road* was in the cellphone.

Are there any ways to fix it?

Comment: I guess that it's due to the previous album cover being still saved in the cache of the app you use to view the albums. See if wiping the app's cache helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, album art caching sucks.. I know exactly what you're going through. But I'm pretty sure I have a working solution for turning off auto-relation.

You may or may not need root, depending on if your album cache is stored on `/sdcard/Android` (which usually is the case) or in `/data/data`.

Go into `/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs` -- where all the album arts are stored, and delete all of them.

But that isn't going to fix the problem for future offenders. To do that, we'll have to **disable** caching. I got the idea from a guy on an XDA thread.

To effectively disabling caching, thus turning off auto-relation, change the permissions on the `albumthumbs` folder to **read-only** on all groups. If the folder is part of the app data under `/data/data` it may be difficult to do so, even with root. On Samsung and ZenFone, you won't run into this issue.

Hope this helps!